# Can't find the new image in the blue reference folder

Tags: ios, objective-c

Now my app has a blue reference folder, and the app can load images.\

[image]

The code is below:

```
NSString *bundelPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YSPSdk" ofType:@"bundle"];

        NSBundle *sdkBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundelPath];

        for (int i = 1; i <= 72; i++)
        {
            NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"adapte_animation_%03d@3x",i];

            NSString *imagePath = [sdkBundle pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"Loading"];

            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

            [_imageArray addObject:image];
        }
```

The app builds and runs well.

Then I add some new images into this folder, and change the code as below:

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"animation_%03d",i];

            NSString *imagePath = [sdkBundle pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"Loading"];

            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

            [_imageArray addObject:image];
        }
```

[image]

The app will crash.
 Then I debugged this app and set a breakpoint in the code.
I see the image not be created.
   Why?
   I must replace the old image with the new image.
   What is a remedy in this case?

==============

I rename some old Images and edit the code to load this new name old images.
I run the app, the app shows me the same error:

[image]

It can't find the imagePath!

Comment: Is there any information log of crash?

Comment: Check if the file is added as a resource, in the project, select the file go in the right side bar and check if the file is checked in correct target.

Answer (score 0):

In my main project.  TARGETS ->  Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources.

I delete the `YSPSdk.bundle` and add it again. I solve the problem.